# insertAsFristElement was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

i have this home work about workers data general and as my ways as i put it i still have this error .If anyone would help me please.
this is the code sory for the lang it's Albanian  :

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct pun{
    char Emri[20];
    char Mbiemri[20];
    int Mosha , ID;
    char Vendlindja[20];
    char Arsimi[30];
    int Datpunesim;
    int Eksperienca;
    int Datepushimi;
    pun *next;
};
bool isEmpty(pun *head);
  char menu();
  void insertAsFristElement(pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID);
  void insert (pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID);
  void remove (pun *&head, pun *&last);
  void showlist(pun *&current);
  bool isEmpty (pun *head){
    if (head == NULL)
        return  true;
    else 
        return false;
  }
  char menu(){
    char choice ;
    cout <<"Menuja...\n";
    cout <<"1. Fusni te dhenat:...\n";
    cout <<"2. Fshini te dhenat:...\n";
    cout <<"3. Shfaqe Listen:...\n";
    cout <<"4. Dil....\n";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
  }
  void insertAsFristElement(pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID){
    pun *temp = new pun;
    temp->ID = ID;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
  }
  void insert (pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID){
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head,last,ID);
    else{
        pun *temp = new pun;
    temp->ID = ID;
    temp->next = NULL;
    last->next = temp;
    last = temp;
    }
  }
  void remove (pun *&head, pun *&last){
    if(isEmpty( head ))
        cout <<"Lista eshte boshe.\n";
    else if (head==last){
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    else{
        pun *temp=head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
  }
  void showlist(pun *&current){
    if (isEmpty(current))
        cout<< "Lista eshte boshe :.....\n";
    else{
        cout <<"Permbajtja e Listes :...\n";
        while (current!=NULL){
            cout <<current->ID <<endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
  }
int main(){
    pun *head=NULL;
    pun *last=NULL;
    char choice;
    int ID;
    int n;
    pun x[n];
    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice){
            case '1': for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
                cout<<"Vendosni ID e personit:....";
                cin>>x[i].ID;
                cout<<"Vendosni Emrin:......\n";
                cin>>x[i].Emri;
                cout<<"Vendosni Mbiemrin:....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Mbiemri;
                cout<<"Vendosni moshen:....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Mosha;
                cout<<"Vendosni vendlindjen:....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Vendlindja;
                cout<<"Vendosni Arsimin:.....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Arsimi;
                cout<<"Vendosni Eksperiencen:.....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Eksperienca;
                cout<<"Vendosni Daten e punesimit:....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Datpunesim;
                cout<<"Vendosni Daten e pushimit:.....\n";
                cin>>x[i].Datepushimi;
                insert(head,last,ID);
                break;
                }

            case '2': remove (head,last);
                break;
            case '3':showlist(head);
                break;
            default : cout <<"Po dilni nga sistemi ..........\n";
        }
    }
    while (choice !='4');
    return 0;
}
```

[this is a pic after compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dGuN.jpg)

Comment: Check your spelling more carefully.

Comment: You misspelled it: `insertAsFirstElement()` it should be in all cases.

Comment: u say i should put insertAsFirstElement () in all cases it does not make any sense

Comment: @EltonBendaj Just the symbol `insertAsFirstElement`! Leave parameters as you need to. `insertAsFirstElement` != `insertAsFristElement`. Put on your glasses please.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
void insertAsFristElement(pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID);
             ^^^^^
```

or

```
  void insert (pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID){
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head,last,ID);
                ^^^^^
```

I think you mean

```
void insertAsFirstElement(pun *&head, pun *&last, int ID);
             ^^^^^
```

Comment: look man at first case i have the input of the data and the input of those data  is made by the code that is giving me the mistake but anyway thnx